# Open Chrome with selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, web

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/myPC/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

So I downloaded chromedriver.exe and tried opening Chrome using the following code, but every time I run this code I get the following error:

```
Error:java: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
```

And also whenever I try and run chromedriver.exe from desktop, chrome does not want to open.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to add it to your libs and start it from it example (System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","libs\\chromedriver.exe"))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some more information about what/why/how you're trying to accomplish, and what you've tried so far, would be helpful.  There are [some tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about posting questions.  Have you checked out the many [posts from others](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Error:java:+package+com.google.common.collect+does+not+exist) who had similar issues?

Comment: You need to put jar files too

Comment: @crammeur I tried and I still receive the same error

Comment: Do you have jar files example of one (selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar) and (client-combined-3.4.0-nodeps.jar)

Comment: @crammeur I did and now it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/myPC/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: This looks like merely a copy of the code from the question, and not an answer at all.

Comment: `driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");`. Can you please explain why you should use this bit of code over `driver.get("http://www.google.com");`. Code dumps don't do much and can actually cause confusion.

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation instead of a `code only answer`.

Comment: @tripleee the last line, `driver.navigate().to` is different.